# While using Django GraphQL Auth package, I am able to achieve all the functionality but somehow the passwordReset mutation is always timing out. Why?

Tags: django, graphql, django-graphql-auth

I have a GraphQL API in Django which uses the Django GraphQL Auth package for implementing auth related mutations. All of my code works as it did before except for the passwordReset mutation. I have a timeout at 30 seconds in my Gunicorn server and always the passwordReset mutation timesout.

I am not seeing any errors in the log.

I tried running it locally and the same code seems to work just fine.

This seems unusual considering I don't see a reason why a passwordReset should take such a long time to resolve.

I am stuck here for a while and don't have any leads on this. Help!

Comment: try to specify `--timeout` while running gunicorn server becouse gunicorn default timeout is `30s` check [here](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari, I suppose that could work but unfortunately I've hosted my app on Heroku and it doesn't allow a request to go past 30s even if you have configured the Gunicorn server to allow for it. Not sure if there's a workaround. But the odd thing is that this used to work just fine earlier. I don't know what changed. My code didn't change. I checked with earlier commit too. I just can't pinpoint how this happened suddenly and definitely seems mysterious as to why it happens only to the passwordReset mutation. Everything else works fine.

Comment: Hello @RagavY provide your **`passwordReset`** view inside your question & it's difficult to provide solution becouse your question does not contain any errors so it's better you ask this question on [**salesforce.stackexchange.com**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/)